# Looping through aggregated data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, na

I'm trying to impute missing values in a data frame specific column.

My intention is to replace it by means of groups of other column.

I've saved aggregated results using `aggregate`:

```
# Replace LotFrontage missing values by Neighborhood mean
lot_frontage_by_neighborhood = aggregate(LotFrontage ~ Neighborhood, combined, mean)
```

And now I want to implement something like this:

```
for key, group in lot_frontage_by_neighborhood:
    idx = (combined["Neighborhood"] == key) & (combined["LotFrontage"].isnull())
    combined[idx, "LotFrontage"] = group.median()
```

This is of course a python code.

Not sure how to achieve this in R, can someone please help?

For example:

```
Neighborhood  LotFrontage
     A            20
     A            30
     B            20
     B            50
     A           <NA>
```

NA Record should be replace with 25 (Average LotFrontage of all records in Neighborhood A)

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide sample data with expected output?

Comment: @count Added, Thanks

Comment: `require(dplyr)`; `dat %>% group_by(Neighborhood) %>% mutate(LotFrontage
 = ifelse(is.na(LotFrontage
),mean(LotFrontage
,na.rm=TRUE),LotFrontage
))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the idea you are looking for? You may need the which() function to determine which rows have NA values.

```
set.seed(1)
Neighborhood = sample(letters[1:4], 10, TRUE)
LotFrontage = rnorm(10,0,1)
LotFrontage[sample(10, 2)] = NA

# This data frame has 2 columns. LotFrontage column has 10 missing values.
df = data.frame(Neighborhood = Neighborhood, LotFrontage = LotFrontage)

# Sets the missing values in the Neighborhood column to the mean of the LotFrontage values from the rows with that Neighborhood
x<-df[which(is.na(df$LotFrontage)),]$Neighborhood
f<-function(x) mean(df[(df$Neighborhood==x),]$LotFrontage, na.rm =TRUE)
df[which(is.na(df$LotFrontage)),]$LotFrontage <- lapply(x,f)
```

Comment: Not exactly. Say I have 3 neighborhoods `A, B, C`, and a record X in which `LotFrontage` is `NA`, and its neigborhood is `B`. I want to replace missing value with `mean( all records which has neighborhood B )`

Comment: So, is LotFrontage a quantitative variable, but neighborhoods is a qualitative variable?

Comment: Yes, I've added an example in the main post. Thanks

Comment: Okay, I just edited my answer. Is this the idea you were thinking?

Comment: Exactly, thanks. One thought - the mean calculation is ignoring missing values records, right?

Comment: After trying git gives incorrect values of 0.x (for values in range of 30-100)

Comment: @Adiel I'm sorry. I saw an error as well. I just fixed it. The NA values are removed before the mean is calculated. You can feel free to check my newest answer and let me know if it seems to be working from your perspective too!

Comment: Hi friend, the calculation seems OK now, but the data frame looks weird afterwards. `head(combined$LotFrontage, n = 15)` before the operation produces: `[1] 65 80 68 60 84 85 75 NA 51 50 70 85 NA 91 NA` , while afterwards it produces: `[[1]]
[1] 65

[[2]]
[1] 80

[[3]]
[1] 68

[[4]]
[1] 60

[[5]]
[1] 84

[[6]]
[1] 85

[[7]]
[1] 75

[[8]]
[1] 81.51765

[[9]]
[1] 51

[[10]]
[1] 50

[[11]]
[1] 70

[[12]]
[1] 85

[[13]]
[1] 74.55102

[[14]]
[1] 91

[[15]]
[1] 75.21067`

In order to resolve i've used `sapply` instead of `lapply`